# How to detect since when a user is logged into the system with .NET (C#)?

Tags: c#, .net

I need to detect the **logged on time** of a user connected to the server by remote desktop or console in C#. I was trying to search a property in the WMI classes but I did not find any.
Thanks again in advance!

Comment: With remote desktop, you can disconnect a session and reconnect later, while the user session stays logged in on the server. What value do you want returned in this situation - time since initial user logon, or length of the most recent RDP session?

Comment: It's ok for me to retrieve the time since initial user logon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [cassia](http://code.google.com/p/cassia/), the .NET Terminal Services Library.

```
ITerminalServicesManager manager = new TerminalServicesManager();
using (ITerminalServer server = manager.GetRemoteServer("your-server-name"))
{
    server.Open();
    foreach (ITerminalServicesSession session in server.GetSessions())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Session ID: " + session.SessionId);
        Console.WriteLine("User: " + session.UserAccount);
        Console.WriteLine("State: " + session.ConnectionState);
        Console.WriteLine("Logon Time: " + session.LoginTime);
    }
}
```

You could also use P/Invoke to access the [Windows Terminal Services API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383468.aspx) directly, but cassia wraps it for you.

Comment: I believe so, it should have a SessionID of 0 and the WindowStationName should be "Console".